# Java creating a queue

Tags: java, queue

I need to create a queue, the information fields of which are: the computer(I suppose it meant the name of the computer) and the amount of its RAM.

The first thing I thought was to create a `computer class` with the corresponding variables - `name` and `ram`.

```
class Computer{
    String name;
    int ram;
    public Computer(String name, int ram){
    . . .

}
. . .
}
```

And then create something like this :

```
Queue<Computer> q= new LinkedList<>();
```

And everything seems to be working well. But I would like to know if it is possible to do without creating a class `Computer`?Like create information fields already when declaring a queue?

Comment: That is not possible. You could just declare these variables in the main class though.

Comment: No that is not really possible nor would it really be a good idea. Having well defined classes is what object oriented programming is all about and makes developing software much easier.

Comment: What about [records](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/language/records.html)?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I don't really see how that is related

Comment: @Jadefalke they're asking how to avoid creating a `Computer` class. They can use records instead. That's how that's related.

Comment: Else, if it is only about avoiding creating a new class, use `Map`. Like `Queue<Map>`.

Comment: Or `Map<String, Integer>`?

Answer (score 0):

While this is not a good way to use `Map.Entry` interface, you could do the following:

```
Queue<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> queue = new LinkedList<>();
Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = Map.entry("computer name", 16);
queue.add(entry);
```